# How to use a list of specialized objects being instances of types that inherits from the same class in C#?

Tags: c#, list, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

Let's suppose I have the classes Bus and Truck, which inherit from Vehicle:

```
class Vehicle
{
    public string Model { get; set; }
}
```

```
class Bus : Vehicle 
{
    public Bus(string model, int passengers)
    {
        Model = model;
        MaxPassengers = passengers;
    }
    public int MaxPassengers { get; set; }
}
```

```
class Truck : Vehicle
{
    public Truck(string model, int weight)
    {
        Model = model;
        MaxWeight = weight;
    }
    public int MaxWeight { get; set; }
}
```

That being said, I want to allow the user to create new Truck or Bus classes and want to save them. The best way I could come up with was making a List, but I have to make it to accept both Truck and Bus objects.

At first I thought about making a Vehicle list. This is what I came up with:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Vehicle> allVehicles = new List<Vehicle>();

        Console.Write("[Bus] Insert model: ");
        string busModel = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("[Bus] Insert max passengers: ");
        int busPassengers = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("[Truck] Insert model: ");
        string truckModel = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("[Truck] Insert weight capacity: ");
        int truckWeight = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        allVehicles.Add(new Bus(busModel, busPassengers));
        allVehicles.Add(new Truck(truckModel, truckWeight));
    }
}
```

The code above compiles, but I can't access their specific properties (MaxPassengers of Bus objects and MaxWeight of Truck objects). Casting doesn't seem to work either. The following statement does not compile:

```
Console.WriteLine((Bus)allVehicles[0].MaxPassengers);
```

Am I missing something? Do I have to make a list for each class?

Comment: How are you going to use them? If you are constantly checking which is which, then why not create two lists so you won't have to worry about it?

Comment: This is an example. I'm going to need them for some specific situations, but I'll also have to use them mixed. The thing is: there are not only two child classes. There are a lot. Creating a list for every single one of them and using all of the lists together sometimes seems to be a bit wrong and inefficient...

Comment: Have you considered having two lists but a facade layer that concatenates them behind the scene (if that's what you occasionally need). Take a look at: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6eiAQm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All is fine and clean with the code provided.

You simply need to add brackets for the cast else it try to cast `MaxPassengers` and that fails:

```
if ( allVehicles[0] is Bus )
  Console.WriteLine(((Bus)allVehicles[0]).MaxPassengers);
```

Or [explicitly convert](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#as-operator):

```
if ( allVehicles[0] is Bus )
  Console.WriteLine((allVehicles[0] as Bus).MaxPassengers);
```

[Null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) can be used too to avoid the if:

```
Console.WriteLine((allVehicles[0] as Bus)?.MaxPassengers);
```

Also you can use [pattern-matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching) with C# 7+:

```
if ( allVehicles[0] is Bus bus)
  Console.WriteLine(bus.MaxPassengers);
```

You can filter the collection too:

```
using System.Linq;

var allBus = allVehicles.OfType<Bus>();

foreach ( var bus in allBus )
  Console.WriteLine(bus.MaxPassengers);
```

Comment: Your second example will cause a `NullReferenceException` is `allVehicles[0]` isn't a `Bus`. If you're certain it's a `Bus`, just use `((Bus)allVehicles[0])` -- if you're wrong, an `InvalidCastException` is a lot more helpful than a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: @BenM: I'm not following, the two example that include casts to `Bus` (either with `(Bus)` or `as Bus`) are guarded by `if (allVehicles[0] is Bus)`.  At that point, it's known that `allVehicles[0]` is, in fact, a `Bus`

Comment: @Flydog57 - Initially this answer didn't have the `if` statement in the second code block. That has since been fixed. But in general, I think developers overuse the `as` operator. I've spent too much time debugging code where an `as` statement causes a `NullReferenceException` to appear several levels deeper in the code, where an unsafe cast would have caused an `InvalidCastException` right where the cast was happening.